# How to add button at the end of a loop with twig

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, twig, timber

**UPDATE : I answer to my question with a solution who work. See below.**

I created a loop that displays posts. Each two iteration a new `row` is created.

My loop iterate around this list of posts. The button is not considered in this array.
But my problem is that I would like to add a button in the last col.

In the options of my back office I give the possibility to show or not this button. So sometime I don't need to add a last col with this button.

Furthermore I need to add `col-md-push-2` on each column on two because I use a Bootstrap grid (even on the column of the button when the button is active in the back office).

[image]

I wrote this code who work fine. But I don't know where to add my button.

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="row">
        {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 {% if loop.index is even %}col-md-push-2{% endif %}">
            <div class="div-for-my-content">
                Col content
            </div>
            {% if buttonIsActive %}
            <div class="div-for-my-button">
                Button
            </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
{% if loop.index % 2 == 0 and not loop.last %}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="group">
    <div class="row">
{% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't know where can I add the code for my button. I know that I actually have my button in each row :-(

Example of html I try to generate.

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 ">
            <div class="div-for-my-content">
                Col content
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-md-push-2">
            <div class="div-for-my-content">
                Col content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 ">
            <div class="div-for-my-content">
                Col content
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-md-push-2">
            <div class="div-for-my-content">
                Col content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
            <div class="div-for-my-button">
                Button
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to place the button at the right spot, inside an open row, or open a new row you could check if the count of the items inside posts is even or not. Do note, u'd need to do the test twice, once for even and once for uneven

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="row">
        {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 {% if loop.index is even %}col-md-push-2{% endif %}">
            <div class="div-for-my-content">
                Col content
            </div>
            {% if loop.last and posts|length % 2 != 0 %}
            <div class="div-for-my-button">
                Button
            </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
{% if loop.index % 2 == 0 and not loop.last %}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="group">
    <div class="row">
{% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% if posts|length % 2 == 0 %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
            <div class="div-for-my-button">
                Button
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/s1vdzo)

Comment: Thank you again for your new help. In fact I must test if my posts length is divisible by 2 for add my button ? I tested and I now I have my button in each column :-/. In fact I try to put my button in a separate column. I updated my post with the html I try to generate

Comment: In fact I set up your logic. And I have a button in each column. The button is in the same col-xs-12... as my content

Comment: My mistake there, should have added `loop.last` to ensure it only will go in the last row.

Comment: Perfect again ! Thank you for your explanation ! I understand the logic now. If I summarize. Each time the length of my posts list is divisible by 2 I create a new row and one col for my button, if my list is not divisible by 2, I add the button in the last col of the last row.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I'm guessing you could solve this with the [batch](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/batch.html) filter as well, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55052306/446594) but I'm not to familiar with it at this point

Comment: I did not know this function. I guess it could simplify my code ! In any case your solution works very well. Thank you again

Comment: I succeeded to use batch function ! Thank you !

Comment: You should post the `batch` variant as wel ;-)

Comment: I added a answer with the variant. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

I answer to my question with a variant who work and use `batch`.

```
{% for row in posts|batch(2) %}
<div class="group">
    <div class="row">
        {% for item in row %}
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 {% if loop.index is even %}col-md-push-2{% endif %}">
            <div class="div-for-my-content">
                Col content
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        {% if btn_statut == true and loop.last and posts|length is not divisible by(2) %}
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-md-push-2">
            <div class="div-for-my-button">
                Button
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
{% if btn_statut == true and loop.last and posts|length is divisible by(2) %}
<div class="group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
            <div class="div-for-my-button">
                Button
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```